# Instantiating variables ending in a digit using where-attribute (Isabelle)

Tags: isabelle

In Isabelle, given a theorem thm with a free variable `x` (more precisely, a schematic variable), one can instantiate `x` using the `where`-attribute.

E.g., `thm[where x=5]`

I am unable to make this work if the variable name ends in a number, e.g., `thm[where x1=5]`. This seems to be due to the fact that the variable is represented in the theorem as "?x1.0" and not as "?x1".

The theory below gives an example.

My question is: How do I instantiate x1 in such a theorem? (E.g., the theorem in the theory below.)

"Solutions" that I am aware of:
 - Using `thm[of 1]` instead of `thm[where x1=1]`. That works in some cases, but for theorems with many variables this becomes very unwieldy and unstable (the order of variables may change).
 - Using only variable names not ending in digits. That would work, but sometimes variables like x1 are very natural in the given context.

```
theory Tmp imports Main begin

lemma l1: "x+y=y+(x::nat)" by simp

thm l1[where x=1]
(* Prints: 1 + ?y = ?y + 1 *)

lemma l2: "x1+x2=x1+(x2::nat)" by simp

thm l2[where x1=1]
(* Prints: No such variable in theorem: "?x1" *)

thm l2
(* Prints: ?x1.0 + ?x2.0 = ?x1.0 + ?x2.0 *)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use the full name of the schematic variable including the question mark:

```
thm l2[where ?x1.0 = 1]
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I had tried `thm l2[where "?x1.0"=1]`. Close...

Do you know whether this is an intentional design choice? (`x1=1` would seem much more intuitive and more readable to me.) Looking at the source of `where` (especially `scan_vname` in lexicon.ML) it does not seem to hard to fix, but perhaps there are other technical reasons that I am not aware of...

Comment: The question mark notation also works for variables that do not end with a digit (e.g., `thm l1[where ?x.0=1]`), so this is really the general form, but it is hardly ever used. The shorthand `thm l[where x2=...]` with a digit at the end actually refers to the variable `?x.2` rather than `?x2.0`, probably for historical reasons. Such non-zero indices are relatively rare in practice, but they do occur in theorems, e.g., the rule exported from `{ fix x assume "x=x" }`. So at present, the notation `x1` cannot be used to refer to ?x1.0. One could change that of course...